# How to scatter plot each group of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, scatter-plot

I am making a scatter plot with the geyser dataset from seaborn. I am coloring the points based on the 'kind' column but for some reason, the legend only shows 'long' but leaves out 'short'. I don't know what I am missing. I also was wondering if there is a simpler way to color code the data one that does not use a for-loop.

#### `geyser_df.head()`

```
     duration  waiting   kind
0       3.600       79   long
1       1.800       54  short
2       3.333       74   long
3       2.283       62  short
4       4.533       85   long
```

```py
x = geyser_df['waiting']
y = geyser_df['duration']
col = []

for i in range(len(geyser_df)):
    if (geyser_df['kind'][i] == 'short'):
        col.append('MediumVioletRed')
    elif(geyser_df['kind'][i] == 'long'):
        col.append('Navy')

plt.scatter(x, y, c=col)
plt.legend(('long','short'))
plt.xlabel('Waiting')
plt.ylabel("Duration")
plt.suptitle("Waiting vs Duration")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The correct way to do this with pandas is with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
df = sns.load_dataset('geyser')

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
colors = {'short': 'MediumVioletRed', 'long': 'Navy'}
for kind, data in df.groupby('kind'):
    data.plot(kind='scatter', x='waiting', y='duration', label=kind, color=colors[kind], ax=ax)

ax.set(xlabel='Waiting', ylabel='Duration')
fig.suptitle('Waiting vs Duration')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- The easiest way is with `seaborn`, a high-level API for matplotlib, where `hue` is used to separate groups by color.

  - [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html): an axes-level plot
  - [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html): a figure-level plot where `kind='scatter'` is the default plot style

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
colors = {'short': 'MediumVioletRed', 'long': 'Navy'}
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='waiting', y='duration', hue='kind', palette=colors, ax=ax)

ax.set(xlabel='Waiting', ylabel='Duration')
fig.suptitle('Waiting vs Duration')
plt.show()
```

```py
colors = {'short': 'MediumVioletRed', 'long': 'Navy'}
p = sns.relplot(data=df, x='waiting', y='duration', hue='kind', palette=colors, height=4, aspect=1.5)

ax = p.axes.flat[0]  # extract the single subplot axes

ax.set(xlabel='Waiting', ylabel='Duration')
p.fig.suptitle('Waiting vs Duration', y=1.1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `x = geyser_df ['waiting']` and `y = geyser_df ['duration']` as a single dataset which causes `plt.scatter` to only use as `label="long"` as legend. I don't have enough experience using this type of *libraries* but to reproduce the example you describe you need to write a program like this:

```
long = [[], []]
short = [[], []]
col=['MediumVioletRed', 'Navy']

for i in range(len(geyser_df["kind"])):
  if (geyser_df["kind"][i] == "long"):
      long[0].append([geyser_df['waiting'][i]])
      long[1].append([geyser_df['duration'][i]])
  else:
      short[0].append([geyser_df['waiting'][i]])
      short[1].append([geyser_df['duration'][i]])

plt.scatter(long[0], long[1], c=col[1], label="long")
plt.scatter(short[0], short[1], c=col[0], label="short")

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Waiting')
plt.ylabel("Duration")
plt.suptitle("Waiting vs Duration")
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]